# Spring cloud stream create and delete topics programmatically

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a requirement where I need to create and delete Kafka topics programmatically. `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BinderAwareChannelResolver` . `resolveDestination(String channelName)` can create a topic, but this is deprecated.
Also, there is no way to delete Kafka topic programmatically which I am aware of.

Any suggestions to achieve this are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `AdminClient` to create and delete topics.
Spring Boot will auto-configure a `KafkaAdmin` and you can use `kafkaAdmin.getConfigurationProperties()` to create an admin client with `AdminClient.create(props)` (or you can just use your own properties).